# why ffplay can play rtp stream without sdp?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtp

I found a rtp h264 stream with payload type 98, it can be directly play without sdp file by run
ffplay -v trace  -i udp://127.0.0.1:9880, but it's a rtp stream.

I built a stream by run

ffmpeg   -re -framerate 10 -loop 1 -i ./raw.jpeg -vcodec libx264  -bf 0 -g 24  -payload_type 98  -f rtp  rtp://127.0.0.1:9880

then,run ffplay -v trace  -i udp://127.0.0.1:9880

output:

```
Initialized opengl renderer.
[NULL @ 0x7f58d4000b80] Opening 'udp://127.0.0.1:9880' for reading
[udp @ 0x7f58d4001680] No default whitelist set
[udp @ 0x7f58d4001680] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
Probing mp3 score:1 size:2048q=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
Probing mp3 score:1 size:4096
Probing mp3 score:1 size:8192
Probing mp3 score:1 size:16384
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f58d4021ea0] Statistics: 1049843 bytes read, 0 seeks
udp://127.0.0.1:9880: Invalid data found when processing input
```

ffplay can not probe the format

I captured the udp packet,and compared,then found out that stream's every NAL is 0,and my stream's ,some NAL is 0,some NAL is not.

[ NAL is 0 in every rtp packet]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm0Pq.png

[ NAL is not 0 ]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT0Im.png

How to build a rtp h264 stream with every NAL is 0?

Why that rtp stream can be play without sdp file?
Thanks

Comment: RTP uses the SDP protocol to negotiate session characteristics between endpoints. An endpoint (a browser or other software running for a user) *sends* SDP to say "these formats are what I know how to receive". Once the SDP negotiation is complete, the senders of RTP streams use the negotiated format. It's no surprise that you can decode such an RTP stream: ffplay can determine its format from information embedded in the stream, particularly in the PPS and SPS NALUs.

Answer (score 0):

RTP uses the SDP protocol to negotiate session characteristics between endpoints. An endpoint (a browser or other software running for a user) *sends* SDP to say "these formats are what I know how to receive". Once the SDP negotiation is complete, the senders of RTP streams use the negotiated format. It's no surprise that you can decode such an RTP stream: ffplay can determine its format from information embedded in the stream, particularly in the PPS and SPS NALUs.